# Catching an exception and imputing some value with pandas apply() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, exception, python-requests

I wrapped into a function a procedure that extracts text from urls:

```
def text(link):
    article = Article(link)
    article.download()
    article =  article.parse()
    return article
```

I am planning to apply this function to a pandas column:

```
df['text'] = df['links'].apply(text)
```

However, some links of `links` column are broken (i.e. `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`). So my question is, how can I add a NaN to the broken urls, and pass them?. I tried to do:

```
from newspaper import Article
import numpy as np
import requests

def text(link):
    article = Article(link)
    try:
        article.download()
        article = article.parse()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        return np.nan
    return article

df['text'] = df['links'].apply(text)
```

Nevertheless, I do not know if it is possible to handle the `apply()` function in order to impute a `NaN` value to the cell which it's link is broken.

**UPDATE**

I tried to handle it with `ArticleException` as follows:

df:

```
title   Link
Inside tiny tubes, water turns solid when it should be boiling  http://news.mit.edu/2016/carbon-nanotubes-water-solid-boiling-1128
Four MIT students named 2017 Marshall Scholars  http://news.mit.edu/2016/four-mit-students-marshall-scholars-11282
Saharan dust in the wind    http://news.mit.edu/2016/saharan-dust-monsoons-11231
The science of friction on graphene http://news.mit.edu/2016/sliding-flexible-graphene-surfaces-1123
```

In:

```
import numpy as np
from newspaper import Article, ArticleException
import requests

def text_extractor2(link):
    article = Article(link)
    try:
        article.download()
    except ArticleException:
        article = article.parse()
        return np.nan
    return article

df['text'] = df['Link'].apply(text_extractor2)
df
```

Out:

```
    title   Link    text
0   Inside tiny tubes, water turns solid when it s...   http://news.mit.edu/2016/carbon-nanotubes-wate...   <newspaper.article.Article object at 0x10c8a0320>
1   Four MIT students named 2017 Marshall Scholars  http://news.mit.edu/2016/four-mit-students-mar...   <newspaper.article.Article object at 0x1070df0f0>
2   Saharan dust in the wind    http://news.mit.edu/2016/saharan-dust-monsoons...   <newspaper.article.Article object at 0x107b035c0>
3   The science of friction on graphene     http://news.mit.edu/2016/sliding-flexible-grap...   <newspaper.article.Article object at 0x10c8bf8d0>
```

Comment: By broken, you mean the links point to an invalid URL? Have you tried returning `numpy.nan` if the link is invalid?

Comment: @PyNoob Sorry, with broken what I meant to say was that: `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you want the row corresponding to the broken link to have a NaN value in the `text` column. We can first add the `numpy` import if you haven't already:

```
import numpy as np
```

I am assuming the exception thrown is `HTTPError`, and will use NumPy for its NaN value:

```
def text(link):
    article = Article(link)

    try:
        article.download()
    except HTTPError:
        return np.nan

    article = article.parse()
    return article
```

Then, using pandas [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html),

```
df['text'] = df['links'].apply(text)
```

The text column should contain missing values for broken links and the article text for valid links.

---

Without using `newspaper`, you could alter the function to catch the exception on `ur.urlopen(url).read()`, e.g.

```
def text_extractor(url):
    try:
        html = ur.urlopen(url).read()
    except ur.HTTPError:
        return np.nan

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()
        text = soup.get_text()
        lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
        chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
        text = ' '.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
    sentences = ', '.join(sent_tokenize(str(text.strip('\'"') )))
    return sentences
```

Comment: Right now I can't seem to reproduce that (or even a broken link scenario) using the `newspaper` package. Do you have an example of a broken link and the traceback?

Comment: Thanks for the help!. I tried it and I got again: `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

Comment: Still the same, If newspaper is the problem, I added an alternative version which uses beautiful soup.

Comment: The second actually worked. However, I am also interested in do it with news paper... which solution do you think it's better?..

Comment: It would be good to have it working with newspaper, I think, but that is up to you. Maybe you need to specify where the exception is defined -- e.g. instead of `HTTPError`, use `requests.exceptions.HTTPError` (assuming `requests` is already imported).

Comment: Do you have the full traceback for that HTTPError, e.g. the line when it occurs?

Comment: I tried by importing `ArticleException` as follows:     `except ArticleException:
        article = article.parse()
        return np.nan
    return article`. However a generator is replaced in all the rows of the new column,

Comment: With that code, it seems like it would only parse the article if an exception was reached, which wouldn't make sense. So perhaps the generator is actually the `article` instance? But unfortunately I can't seem to reproduce the errors on my computer.

Comment: I added more info and the full output of my case.